# Is it possible to obtain float touch coordinates in Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, touch

I am working on a project in which I need to use high accuracy input coordinates for further calculation.

I call [GetTouchInputInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371582(v=vs.85).aspx) function in WM_TOUCH message handler to acquire [PTOUCHINPUT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317334(v=vs.85).aspx) variables, but the coordinates provided in this struct are indicated in hundredths of a pixel of physical screen coordinates. So basically the last 2 digits are always 0, and after divided by 100, these coordinates are just integer screen coordinates. I don't know why did they make it in hundredth.

Besides, does the touchscreen sensor gives continuous signal instead of discreet signal?  As I know, there is a thing called touch prediction in Window, it creates a small touch input lag as it holds a few latest input points and do some prediction algorithm to fix these fresh inputs smooth and pretty. Even if the touchscreen can only sense discreet signal, the input should be float anyway after the prediction algorithm right?

I really couldn't find out how to obtain float touch input. Is there any way or any function to achieve this?

Thank you!

And sorry about my English.

Comment: Is this helpful? [**Touch event and click event are same?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18548493/touch-event-and-click-event-are-same)

Comment: @FirstStep: *"Is this helpful?"* - No. It's not even related.

Answer (score 0):

To convert the scaled long coordinates to float do:

```
PTOUCHINPUT pt;
float xf = pt->x / 100.0;
float yf = pt->y / 100.0;
```

Comment: Considering that "the coordinates in this struct are just integer screen coordinates after divided by 100", this would just create integer coordinates divided by 10.000. I don't see how that helps.

Comment: The coordinates are integers with a precision of 0.01 pixel. This will give you a float in pixels.

Comment: the point is like: (34600, 22300), all are given in hundredth and end with 00, I don't think they have precision of 0.01 pixel.@stark

Comment: The precision of the number is 0.01 pixels, but the accuracy of your touch sensor is only one pixel.  That's not surprising given that a stylus or finger is much larger than a pixel.

Comment: That's really up to the manufacturer and driver author. Since touch input usually has a contact area (vs. a single point with a mouse), the coordinates could well be the calculated center of that area. The precision is there, in case a driver vendor wants to use it. Btw. you should either use `double` or the floating point literal `100.0f`. As written, the code produces a warning with just about any compiler.